# How to store self values with Pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.xp_until_level = 20
        self.taxi_car = "Cabbie"
        self.busines = "Нет"
        self.busines_income = 1000
        self.upgrade_cost = 10000
        self.car_speed = 10
        self.car_level = 0
        self.drives_until_new_car = 20

p = Player()
```

I don’t know how to save `self` values. I making my text game and saving data is my number one problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to store `p` into a pickle file for later retrieval?  Please update the question to show the research you’ve carried out, and exactly where you are stuck in storing the instance to a file.

Comment: @S3DEV yeah,i need to save and load all this data

Answer (score 2):

self values are attributes of your instance. Just pickle your insntace (here `p`) and it stores all the attributes:

```py
import pickle

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.xp_until_level = 20
        self.taxi_car = "Cabbie"
        self.busines = "Нет"
        self.busines_income = 1000
        self.upgrade_cost = 10000
        self.car_speed = 10
        self.car_level = 0
        self.drives_until_new_car = 20

p = Player()

pickled = pickle.dumps(p)
new_obj = pickle.loads(pickled)
print(new_obj.taxi_car)  # Cabbie
```

Answer (score 1):

**Storing the class instance to a binary file:**

The class instance (or any other object) can be [stored to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump), or [read from](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load), a pickled (serialised) binary file for later use or archiving.

For example:

```
import pickle

# Create a class instance (as you have done).    
p = Player()

# Store the class instance to a file.
with open('./cabbie.p', 'wb') as f:  # <-- Note the 'wb' mode, for write-binary
    pickle.dump(p, f)
    
# Read the class instance from a file.
with open('./cabbie.p', 'rb') as f:  # <-- Note the 'rb' mode, for read-binary
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Testing:

```
>>> vars(data)

{'money': 0,
 'level': 0,
 'xp': 0,
 'xp_until_level': 20,
 'taxi_car': 'Cabbie',
 'busines': 'Нет',
 'busines_income': 1000,
 'upgrade_cost': 10000,
 'car_speed': 10,
 'car_level': 0,
 'drives_until_new_car': 20}
```

Comment: it is not helping me(,when i restart game, my money = 0

Comment: That's right. If you're resuming a game, the game will need to read the pickle file and create the player instance from *that*, rather than a new instance.

Comment: i tried to print it in console and it prints <__main__.Player object at 0x0000014D00DBECB0>

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's the memory address into which the instance is stored.  Try: `print(data.taxi_car)` - where `data` is the instance read from the file.

Comment: o,it print 0,then i add 5000$,it prints 5000$ then i disabled script, launched again and it prints 0

Comment: Right, let's have a logical think about this. Perhaps even draw a flow diagram on paper - just simple boxes and lines.  1) Game starts up. Does a file exist for this user? Yes, read instance from file. No, create a new instance. 2) Play game. 3) Game over -> store instance to file.  4) Go to step 1.  Does this make sense?

Comment: this is where the problem is that I don’t have game over, I’m trying to do this: the player starts working, after the end of the work the data is saved, and when the game starts, the player gets to the main menu, and the data is already loaded in it

Comment: Ok. You'll need to add a tiny bit of logic to the game startup to determine if the player has a data file. If the user *has* a data file, read their game data from the file - and do *not* create a new `Player` instance. If the user does *not* have a data file, create a new `Player` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pickle is certainly an option. But you might also consider using [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). It's built in to the standard library, so you don't have to install another package. The advantage to ConfigParser is that you get a nice ini style file that is easily human readable. Here's some code:

```
import configparser

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.xp_until_level = 20
        self.taxi_car = "Cabbie"
        self.busines = "Het"
        self.busines_income = 1000
        self.upgrade_cost = 10000
        self.car_speed = 10
        self.car_level = 0
        self.drives_until_new_car = 20

        self.config=configparser.ConfigParser()

    def save_config(self):
        self.config['default'] = {}   # make blank section 'default'
        self.config['default']['money']                = f'{self.money}'
        self.config['default']['level']                = f'{self.level}'
        self.config['default']['xp']                   = f'{self.xp}'
        self.config['default']['xp_until_level']       = f'{self.xp_until_level}'
        self.config['default']['taxi_car']             = self.taxi_car
        self.config['default']['busines']              = self.busines
        self.config['default']['busines_income']       = f'{self.busines_income}'
        self.config['default']['upgrade_cost']         = f'{self.upgrade_cost}'
        self.config['default']['car_speed']            = f'{self.car_speed}'
        self.config['default']['car_level']            = f'{self.car_level}'
        self.config['default']['drives_until_new_car'] = f'{self.drives_until_new_car}'
        with open('settings.ini', 'w') as fid:
            self.config.write(fid)

    def load_config(self):
        self.config.read('settings.ini')
        self.money                = int(self.config['default']['money'])
        self.level                = int(self.config['default']['level'])
        self.xp                   = int(self.config['default']['xp'])
        self.xp_until_level       = int(self.config['default']['xp_until_level'])
        self.taxi_car             = self.config['default']['taxi_car']
        self.busines              = self.config['default']['busines']
        self.busines_income       = int(self.config['default']['busines_income'])
        self.upgrade_cost         = int(self.config['default']['upgrade_cost'])
        self.car_speed            = int(self.config['default']['car_speed'])
        self.car_level            = int(self.config['default']['car_level'])
        self.drives_until_new_car = int(self.config['default']['drives_until_new_car'])

p = Player()
p.save_config()
p.load_config()
print(dict(p.config['default']))
```

There is a lot of extra overhead to load/save data into variables. This is what the `settings.ini` file looks like:

```
[default]
money = 0
level = 0
xp = 0
xp_until_level = 20
taxi_car = Cabbie
busines = Het
busines_income = 1000
upgrade_cost = 10000
car_speed = 10
car_level = 0
drives_until_new_car = 20
```

Comment: it worked a bit for me,it saves all in file but when i restarting my game,all my values not saved(

Comment: You have to call `load_config` somewhere in your game to load the saved values.