# How would I be able to stop and save a python script's progress while it's running?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic choose your own adventure game with python for a class. we have to have the ability to have the user quit at any time and resume where they left off. how do I do this? there's no UI or anything, it's just using the console.

i don't think I can just use lists or variables since those reset when the program stops right?

Comment: You can save data in text files and other formats here is a [helpful link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saving-text-json-and-csv-to-a-file-in-python/) to learn how to do these stuff

Comment: To quit, user will have to enter some kind of command or sequence of keys. Maybe you've already figured this out. For the other part -- saving the state of the game -- probably the game is super simple and you only need to save location. And location might just be an integer. You can write and read this info with [simple file open/write/read statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: For more complex data, or for saving more than one variable, you might consider using [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). It is built into python and reads/writes an [ini style file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) to/from a dictionary-like object. Very convenient for loading/saving variables. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420515/9705687) for a detailed example.